# Read csv file in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, csv

I have a csv file which I want to directly use without creating a table. Is there a way to read and manipulate it directly?

Comment: In a word - no.

Comment: no you have to import it first. Is that a problem for some reason?

Comment: yeah im not alllowed to create a table in that DB, unfortunately.

Comment: the only things you could do are a) request enough access to be able to do that, or b) get someone to import the file for you, or c) write some code in another language which interacts with both the database and the CSV file in order to do whatever task you are attempting (you didn't say what you actually wanted to do with the data, so maybe this doesn't make sense, but without further info we can't really make any more specific suggestions).

Comment: I am using the data to visualize as a graph in a tool. So id simply need the data input only. manipulations can be done on the tool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you can connect to the server, you will be able to create temp table.

For Microsoft SQL;

```
declare @TempTable csvtable 
     (
        firstCol varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        secondCol varchar(50) NOT NULL
     )

BULK INSERT @TempTable FROM 'PathToCSVFile' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')

GO
```

For MySQL;

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE csvtable

LOAD DATA INFILE 'PathToCSVFile' 
INTO TABLE csvtable 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is tagged as MySQL, but I think the question is you just want to run SQL queries on a CSV. If you are open to using Python, you can use [FugueSQL](https://fugue-tutorials.readthedocs.io/tutorials/fugue_sql/index.html) to do that.

A sample Python snippet would be:

```py
from fugue_sql import fsql

query = """
df = LOAD "/path/to/myfile.csv"

SELECT * 
  FROM df
 WHERE col > 1
 PRINT
"""
fsql(query).run()
```

and this will use Pandas to run the query by default. There is also a `SAVE` keyword so you can save the output to another file.